# Detect whether a Windows 8 Store App has a touch screen

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

There are certain elements of Win 8 Store App UI that change based on whether the user has a touch screen. For example, a ScrollViewer, when rendered on a non-touch screen shows a vertical scrollbar. On a touch screen, the scrollbar is hidden.

I would like to tailor my application UI, adding extra controls, for non-touch screen users. Does anyone know if it is possible to detect whether a user has a touch screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Windows.Devices.Input` namespace to detect various capabilities (touch, keyboard, mouse, etc.).  For example, the [TouchCapabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.input.touchcapabilities.aspx) class has a `TouchPresent` property you could check to see if there's a digitizer available.

Take a look at the [Input: Device capabilities sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Input-device-capabilities-31b67745) to see them in action.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using HTML/JS you can query it like this

```
var touchCapabilities = new Windows.Devices.Input.TouchCapabilities();
var isTouchCapable = touchCapabilities.touchPresent;
```