# Query Touch Capabilities for Winrt App

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, touch, capability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect whether a Windows 8 Store App has a touch screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664228/detect-whether-a-windows-8-store-app-has-a-touch-screen)

For WinRT apps, is there a way to query if the device running the App supports touch or not? I ask because I have on screen controls for a game that aren't needed if you don't have touch.

Answer (score 3):

[Windows.Devices.Input.TouchCapabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-tt/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.input.touchcapabilities) should do it.

```
var t = new Windows.Devices.Input.TouchCapabilities();
bool hasTouch = t.TouchPresent != 0;
```

There's a [sample on the dev center](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Input-device-capabilities-31b67745) as well.