# How to detect a touch enabled device (Win 8, C#.NET)

Tags: c#, windows-8, touch

Certain touch features won't work properly in  my application when running on MS Surface Win8 Pro. That's only when the font DPI is set to 150% (unfortunately the default). I want to show a message to the user if they are running my app in Win8 on a touch enabled device to change their dpi setting for better experience. I know how to check for OS version and dpi settings but looking for a way to check if a touch enabled device is present so I don't have to show this message for users running this on other platforms/devices. My app is in C#.Net 4.5.

This is not a Windows 8 app. It's a winform which can be run on Vista/7/8. I don't see Windows.Devices.Input namespace suggested in other post?

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664228/detect-whether-a-windows-8-store-app-has-a-touch-screen

Comment: _"change their dpi setting for better experience"_ - nope. If that is the default, you should change your app to work (better or at all) on that setting.

Comment: I am not using windows 8 app. It's a winform app which can be run in Windows Vista/7/8. How can I get access to Windows.Device.Input...

Comment: @hometoast please read posts carefully and don't misguide users. This is not a Windows 8 store app. The answer is actually here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957751/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-tell-if-a-system-is-touch-enabled